# Swipe panel with default transition none

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use the new version of jquery mobile (1.4.3). I'm linking to them with a navigation. If I click on a link the page is loaded but if I click on the second page on the navigation the page background color will be black and the navigation is overlaying the page.

In the jsfiddle I create a multi page, but the issue looks the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/knobli/yh7guzvu/4/

```
<body>
    <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="b" data-display="reveal">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-theme="a" id="navigation">
            <li><a href="#trainings">Training</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /panel -->
    <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>News</h1>
    <a href="#left-panel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon">Open left panel</a>
    <a href="settings.html" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon">Settings</a>

        </div>
        <!-- /header -->
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-ajax="true" data-inset="false" id="newsList"></ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /content -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="trainings" data-url="trainings">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Trainings</h1>
    <a href="#left-panel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon">Open left panel</a>
    <a href="settings.html" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-nodisc-icon">Settings</a>

        </div>
        <!-- /header -->
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-ajax="true" data-inset="false" id="newsList">
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test</li>
                <li>Test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /content -->
    </div>
</body>

$(function () {
    $("#left-panel").panel();
    $("#navigation").listview();
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';

    $(document).one("swipeleft swiperight", function (e) {
        if ($(".ui-page-active").jqmData("panel") !== "open") {
            if (e.type === "swiperight") {
                $("#left-panel").panel("open");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I try to fix it with an own transition (referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22576986/2136148) and it looks like that this solve the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/yh7guzvu/8/ (slow loading, how can I speed up?)

http://jsfiddle.net/yh7guzvu/6/ (overwrite fade --> faster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was reported to jQuery Mobile and will be fixed in release 1.4.5

See https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7711